# obtener la utilidad (ganancia) de una venta segun historial de lotes (PHP MYSQL)

Tags: php, mysql

estoy en un tremendo dilema, espero puedan ayudarme se los agradeceria bastante.

Tengo estas tablas mysql:

**productos:**

```
-------------------------------
|id_producto|id_canal|unidades|
|123        |1       |15      |
-------------------------------
```

**productos_lotes:** guardo el registro de unidades ingresadas y varia el precio_costo

```
-------------------------------------------------------
|id_producto|id_canal|fecha     |unidades|precio_costo|
|123        |1       |2021-09-24|10      |20.00       |
|123        |1       |2021-09-23|5       |10.00       |
-------------------------------------------------------
```

**productos_ventas:** guardo la cantidad de unidades vendidas, si agrego una nueva venta le sumo las unidades actuales mas la cantidad a vender

```
-------------------------------
|id_producto|id_canal|n_ventas|
|123        |1       |10      |
|123        |2       |5       |
-------------------------------
```

ahora bien yo lo que quisiera es obtener la ganancia que e generado comparando el precio de costo - el precio de venta;

**Lo que yo estoy haciendo:**
guardar todas las cantidades de ventas en una tabla productos_ventas, cosa que yo ya se cuantas unidades estoy vendiendo del producto (update n_ventas+cantidad_a_vender)

y al momento de realizar una venta lo que hago es recorrer todos los lotes del producto e ir sumando `primer lote + siguiente lote` hasta que el resultado me de mayor o igual que n_ventas + cantidad_a_vender y me detengo allí, con esto logre encontrar en que lote me encuentro y despues de esto extraigo cuanto me costo ese lote y hago la siguiente resta (precio_venta_producto - precio_costo_lote) y el resultado es mi utilidad.

yo se que esto no es lo mas ortodoxo pero no se me ocurre una mejor idea, si alguien pudiera ayudarme con este problema estaria muy muy agradecido

notas:

esta es la estructura de la lista de productos al momento de realizar una venta: ($_POST['detalle_venta'])

```
2109241629406588|500.00|10;2109241713471373|100.00|1
```

id_producto | precio_venta (modificable) | unidades a vender ;

Comment: Y quisieras calcular la ganancia mensualmente? Semanalmente? Diario?

Comment: Por lo que entiendo quieres determinar el costo actual del producto que estás vendiendo (de acuerdo al lote al que pertenecería). Yo no me complicaríá demasiado, así como en un determinado momento un producto tiene un precio que es único (sin importar a que lote pertenece), yo utilizaría un costo único (el del último lote, ya que sería el costo actual del producto), ya que tampoco puedes saber realmente a que lote pertenece ese producto, como para obtener el costo a partir de lote. El costo del lote actual seríá el valor mas aproximado del costo de reposición del producto.

Comment: Ten en cuenta que según el método que estás utilizando (el de determinar el costo según la cantidad de unidades vendidades hasta el momento y la cantidad de unidades en cada lote), si vendes varias unidades de un producto  en una venta, podría involucrar unidades de diferentes lotes del producto, y por lo tanto tener diferentes costos (que tendrías que considerar para calcular la ganacia).

Comment: @nachospiu no podria ponerle el costo unico ya que aveces sube o aveces baja y si yo fuerzo a que todos cuesten igual no podria tener una ganancia exacta y no sabria cuanto tengo de utilidad por producto.

Comment: @LilibethQ el calculo de las ganancias en este caso lo necesito por pedido, por ejemplo al momento de hacer una venta que en ese proceso me muestre cuanto estoy ganando en esa venta

Comment: @nachospiu si tengo claro que no va a ser exacto al 100% pero almenos quiero que con un margen de error me arroje a que lote pertenece para saber su precio costo